# redis password authentication using redis.conf

Tags: redis

Using Redis in a Docker container. My Dockerfile is;

```
FROM redis:latest
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
USER redis
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

I can set the password using **redis-cli** with below commands after Redis starts;

```
config set requirepass testpass
auth testpass
```

However, I need to set the password using **redis.conf** because Redis is supposed to have the password already set when it starts. So I tried

```
requirepass testpass
```

in redis.conf file. Then I tried to connect using RDPTools. Password was asked while I connect. That's good. Unfortunately, my password is not authenticated!

While I'm using redis-cli, I'd auth the password by

```
auth testpass
```

That's missing in my redis.conf I believe.
How can I issue this command in **redis.conf**? There is no auth option in it.

Comment: You don't need to issue `auth testpass` in redis.conf. That's for clients to issue. Changes in redis.conf are not processed live, you need to restart the service

Comment: I'm building a brand new docker image with this updated redis.conf and run docker-compose up to start redis, i.e., I'm not updating redis.conf of already running redis instance.